# how to align submenu on top

Tags: html, css, menu

i have a menu (yellow) with a submenu (first column) and another submenu.

I need to know how i can make the submenu always stay on the top.

[image: img]

```
// menu in the middle
.leftMenu ul li .pchild {
    width: 193px;
    list-style: disc!important;
}
// child menu ( on the right )
    .leftMenu ul li .pchild li .childpost {
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 175px;
    width: 413px;
}
```

To make it easy: This is the website : http://www.ruigrok-nederland.nl/

Comment: set the width of each column to 1/3 100% width, which is 33.333%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It currently displays like that because it is relative to the `li` element. You will need to make it relative to the `div.child` element or like that.

For your code add `position:static` to your `.leftMenu ul li .pchild li`. Something like this:

```
.leftMenu ul li .pchild li {
    position:static
}
```

That is, in your `style.css` at line `140`.

#### Update:

For your second question in the comments you will have 2 options:

- use a jQuery plugin like `hoverIntent` or one of the many menu plugins that work like a charm on all platforms
- write your css like this:

Add this new style:

```
.leftMenu ul li div.post{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 175px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 413px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.leftMenu ul li .pchild li:hover .post {
    display: block;
}
```

Remove:

```
padding-left: 20px;
display: none;
position: absolute;

.leftMenu ul li .pchild li:hover .childpost {
    display: block;
}
```

from `.leftMenu ul li .pchild li .childpost`

Change your `padding` values like this on `.leftMenu .child`

`padding: 0 24px 0 0!important;`

Comment: This did the trick :) Thanks, but only 1 problem.
When you try to navigate to : Tourniquets > Carrousel Tourniquets > 

You cant select the last item

Comment: Last item or first(only) item?

Comment: I mean the child(s) of Tourniquets > Carrousel Tourniquets > ( see my website )

Comment: Updated answer. Instructions are a bit harder to follow but it works 100%. I tested on your website. Don't forget to accept the answer and vote.

Comment: P.S. you have a javascript error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `. Google it, there are a lot of answers for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
.leftMenu .child {
    top:35px;
}

.leftMenu ul li {
    position:static;
}
```

The submenu elements were being absolutely positioned relative to the parent `li` elements. Either remove the relative positioning on the `.leftMenu ul li` element or change it to `static`. In addition, you also need to add `top:35px` to `.leftMenu .child`.